# Converting uint8_t* buffer to jobject

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, android-camera2

We are currently working on a specific live image manipulation/effect application, where we are working with NDK and using Camera2 and MediaNDK apis.

I'm using `AImageReader` as a way to call current frames from camera and assign effects in realtime. This works pretty good, we are getting at least 30 fps in hd resolutions.

However, my job also requires me to return this edited image back to the given java endpoint, that is a `(Landroid/media/Image;)V` signatured method. However this can be changed to any other jobject I want, but must be an image/bitmap kind.

I found out that the `AImage` I was using was just a c struct so I'll not able to convert it to jobject.

Our current process is something like this in order:

- `AImageReader_ImageListener` is calling a static method with an assigned `this` context.
- Method uses `AImageReader_acquireNextImage` and if the media is ok, sends it to a child class/object.
- In here we manipulate the image data inside multiple `std::thread` operations, and merge the resulting image. I'm receiving YUV422 formatted data, but I'm converting it to RGB for easier processing.
- Then we lock the mutex, return the resulting data to delegate, and delete the original image.
- Delegate calls a static method that is responsible for finding/asking the Java method.
- Now I need a simple and low-on-resource solution of converting the data at hand to a C++ object that can be represented also as a jobject.

We are using OpenCv in the processes, so it is possible for me to return a Bitmap object, but looks like job consumes more cpu time than I can let it.

How can I approach this problem? Is there a known fast way of converting `uint8_t *buffer` to a image like jobject context?

Comment: Possibly of use: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#faq-how-do-i-share-raw-data-with-native-code

Comment: @fadden problem is, I cannot return a Buffer object. I'm constantly replacing data inside the buffer in background threads. Returning this byte array to Java VM will lock my process. Copying costs a lot too.

Currently we are converting our view screen to OpenGL2 so I can directly write to a memory-shared texture.